# Remove all markers and replace with new set using filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I'm trying to create a jquery/javascript function that would as the title states remove all markers in my `var markersArray` and do a request in my php script to present new markers. I am having hard time doing it because I am bad with JS so here is my code.

I have 3 filters on the page which are **select elements**
here is my JS script

```
      $('#lgu,#category,#type').change(function(){ 

       google.maps.Map.prototype.clearOverlays = function() {
       for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
       markersArray[i].setMap(null);
       }
       }
var lgu = $('#lgu').val();
var category = $('#category').val();
var type = $('#type').val();
        $.get('xmlquery.php', { input: lgu, input2: category, input3:                                       type},function(data){

downloadUrl("xmlspitter.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      markersArray.push(marker);
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
    });
    });

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
    request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
    callback(request, request.status);
    }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
    }

    });
```

Would appreciate any help.

**Note** my I'm noob with JS meaning I'm also noob at debugging it please help.

Comment: [working "categories" map with data from XML](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html).  Doesn't query for new data on change, but may help you find your problem.

Comment: Does your code actually do anything?  Can you provide a link or a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem you are having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your change-callback will create  a function(extends the google.maps.Map-prototype with a function) `clearOverlays()`, but you don't call this function somewhere, e.g :

```
 map.clearOverlays()
```

...so nothing happens.

But I don't see any reason for creating a function here at all, simply run the loop:

```
$('#lgu,#category,#type').change(function(){

  for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++ ) {
    markersArray[i].setMap(null);
  }

  /* continue with your code*/


});
```